# Extracting certain values from a large URL string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I have a big URL hash that is given in string form and need to extract each part of it:

```
type=recovery&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJhdWQiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGV&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=sYlurmTtfrAhyHl39Oqwww&token_type=bearer&type=recovery
```

I have tried substr() but it isn't reliable because each item may have a differing amount of characters each time.

What's the best way to extract type, access_token, expires_in, refresh_token, token_type reliably?

Comment: URL or URLSearchParams ... look it up in MDN docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use URLSearchParams

```js
var urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams("type=recovery&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJhdWQiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGV&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=sYlurmTtfrAhyHl39Oqwww&token_type=bearer&type=recovery")

const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());

console.log(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
// Adding a dummy domain so the string is a valid url
let x = new URL('http://dummydomain.tpl/dummyfile.ext?' + 
'type=recovery&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJhdWQiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGV&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=sYlurmTtfrAhyHl39Oqwww&token_type=bearer&type=recovery');

x.searchParams.get("refresh_token")
```

Comment: and so i've learned something new :)

Comment: Always a good day when one learns. My goal is to learn every day. So far so good